# Apart from click() and submit() method is there any other way to select/click a web element in selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Java

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
//For clicking the button...  
button.click();
```

Is there any other way to click webElement like radio boxes ,Checkboxes     ,buttons etc..?

Comment: Have you tried sending "SPACEBAR" using keys ? Because sometimes spacebar works for selectign checkboxes and radiobuttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to click something, why would you use something else? I guess click() is the best method for elements to be clickable.

Still you can use enter to perform the same.

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
button.sendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: is there any some method called .toggle() which performs action similar as  .click() ?